# How to execute successive javascript commands that open new web pages

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce

I am trying to automate sending emails in Salesforce. I have figured out the javascript commands that I can launch from the console in Chrome, but I have to do them all individually. Once I've pulled up a page, I have 3 commands I need to execute:

```
document.getElementsByName("email")[0].click() 
//this clicks the "send email" button and redirects to a new page

function getTemplate() {
    var html3 = "&template_id=00XU0000000EVQb"
    navigateToUrl(window.location.href + html3);    
} getTemplate();
//this selects the correct email template to use

sendEmail();
//this sends the email
```

I want to be able to execute one function that will accomplish all of this without having to do them all separately. The problem is after the first command, I'm taken to a new page, so I need a way to either pause a bit before the second command is executed, or have the second and third commands execute once the new page is pulled up.

Comment: People nowadays tend to downvote questions according to their opinion on their subject. Downvoting should reflect the **quality** of the question asked, regardless what you think of the matter.

Comment: i think you should look into chrome extensions. to automate console commands, you would want to create a plugin for your browser to automate that for you. also, you can look into VBA internet explorer automation, it is very easy to achieve your goal using Visual Basic for Applications from any ms office product.